# Querying with id and other fields vs querying with id and checking others after

Tags: python, django, relational-database

For a large number of posts, it's faster (and thus better) to grab the object with the id only and then check if the user matches, right?

```
# Option A
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id, owner=request.user)

# Option B
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
if post.owner != request.user:
    raise Http404()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say large DB, do you mean a 'wide table' with lots of fields or a 'large table' with lots of rows?

I am assuming you intended to say 'wide table' with lots of fields.

Database fetch performance depends on several factors:

- which columns you are fetching,
- what query you are using to fetch,
- filter criteria,
- query plan used by the DB engine,
- are requested columns already in the index or does the database page need to be fetched
  etc.,

Your example refers to fetching a post by id, which is the primary key.
You are fetching the owner and post_id.
Although you haven't shown it in the example, you are likely using other fields of the post (for display etc.,).
So, it is very likely that the primary key index will be fetched and there will be a database page lookup also because the PK index doesn't have owner field or the other queried fields.

So, it doesn't matter whether you use Option A or B, you will get similar performance.

In general, if a table has M fields and you are querying N fields (including all fields in the where clause) with N being a lot smaller than M, you can avoid a database page lookup by indexing the N fields so that the query can be fulfilled directly from the index. It adds overhead for inserts and updates and they will be slower, but your reads will be faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I meant a table with lots of rows and edited the question to clarify that. Does it still make no difference? I am not creating any indexes but I don't know if Django does that automatically.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter. Your query performance is bounded by the volume of data. So, if you want post with id 12345, the database engine will have to lookup the primary key index for 12345 to find which db page contains that row and then check the db cache if that page is present. If the page is not in cache, it will have to load the page into cache and then return your query results. I don't know how Django creates indices to comment. But looks like your query performance is dominated by data volumes and not your query fields. In any case, you are fetching the data and then deciding in the app